# Python 3: Insertion Sort comparisons counter

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, comparison, insertion-sort

I need to add a counter of total comparisons for my Insertion Sort program but I don't know why I'm getting a total of 0 comparisons!

I know that the comparisons output should be 15 (for my specific array) not 0.

This is my code so far:

```
def insertionSort(values):
    k = 0
    n = len(values) - 1
    comparisons = 0
    while k+1 <= n:
        i = k
        while values[i] > values[i+1]:
            temp = values[i]
            values[i] = values[i+1]
            values[i+1] = temp
            comparisons += 1 #I think this is wrong
        k = k + 1
    return comparisons, values
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your code and its not serving the purpose for sorting [7,5,4,6].

Here's a modified version -

```
def insertionSort_mod(values):
    k = 0
    n = len(values) - 1
    comparisons = 0
    while k+1 <= n:
        i = k+1
        curr_val = values[i]
        comparisons += 1
        while i>0 and values[i-1] > curr_val:
            values[i] = values[i-1]
            i=i-1
            comparisons += 1
        values[i] = curr_val
        k = k + 1
    return comparisons, values

print insertionSort_mod( [1, 2, 3, 55, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 111])
```

Outputs this:

```
(15, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 55, 111])
```

In your context k+1 should be the current index so i should be k+1 and should be compared to the previous value i-1

Comment: I just tried your modified version thank you, but when i test with the array [1, 2, 3, 55, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 111] , it gives me a total comparisons of '6', should be 15.

Comment: the comparisons variable undergoes an increment only if there's a swap, so its not exactly reporting the number of comparisons that are happening. To report it fully, you need to increment your counter before the inner while and inside the inner while loop - both the places.

`while k+1 <= n:
        i = k+1
        curr_val = values[i]
        comparisons += 1
        while i>0 and values[i-1] > curr_val:
            values[i] = values[i-1]
            i=i-1
            comparisons += 1`
Do this modification that should do it...

Comment: There you go, now it works like magic. Thank you very much Vivek!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

```
def insertion(a,length):
    count=0
    for i in range(1,length):
        key=a[i]
        jj=i
        while(jj>0 and a[jj-1]>key):
            a[jj]=a[jj-1]
            jj=jj-1
            count += 1
        a[jj]=key
    print count
```

The no. of swaps would be equal to the number of elements for which you shift the elements using the while loop. So, you could use a flag variable inside the while loop, to check if the loop runs for each element, and increase the counter variable by 1, every time the flag variable shows swapping.